# get auth0 user metadata as part of user information

Tags: php, auth0

I don't find how to get the user_metadata from the Auth0 Authentication api:

```
$auth0Api = new Authentication($domain, $clientId, $clientSecret);

$tokenInfo = $auth0Api->login([
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'realm' => 'Username-Password-Authentication',
]);
$accessToken = $tokenInfo["access_token"];

$info = $auth0Api->userinfo($accessToken);
```

The final `$info` array only contains the main user information, no meta_data at all. I tried creating a rule from the Auth0 side to add stuff to the user itself (doing `user.customtag = 'helloworld'` for example) and the customization does not show either.

User info retrieved:

```
{
  "sub":"auth0|XXXX",
  "name":"XXXX@XXXX.com",
  "nickname":"XXXX",
  "picture":"XXXX.png",
  "updated_at":"2017-03-31T08:50:59.819Z",
  "email":"XXXX@XXXX.com",
  "email_verified":true
}
```

The "Raw Json" tab of that user shows something much more complete:

```
{
    "email": "XXXX@XXXX.com",
    "email_verified": true,
    "user_id": "auth0|XXXX",
    "picture": "XXXX.png",
    "nickname": "XXXX",
    "identities": [
        {
            "user_id": "XXXX",
            "provider": "auth0",
            "connection": "Username-Password-Authentication",
            "isSocial": false
        }
    ],
    "updated_at": "2017-03-31T08:50:59.819Z",
    "created_at": "2017-03-23T16:03:47.075Z",
    "name": "XXXX",
    "user_metadata": {
        "languageCode": "EN"
    },
    "last_ip": "XXXX",
    "last_login": "XXXX",
    "logins_count": XXXX,
    "blocked_for": [],
    "guardian_enrollments": []
}
```

How is it supposed to work?

Environment:

- composer: "auth0/auth0-php": "~5.0"
- php 7.1
- Auth0 Free account

Comment: Can you offer more info please - what libraries / versions you are using / whether your Auth0 tenant has OIDC Conformance enabled etc. This context would assist in determining an appropriate answer (I'd like to help you but overall "it depends" on quite a number of factors what the behaviour will be).

Comment: @arcseldon I added the information I had about all that - I have no idea about the OIDC thing

Comment: Just checked and this currently works for me on a quick sample I ran - in so far as both the ID Token and user profile contain data from the "metadata" fields

Comment: Does the profile in question (in Auth0 Dashboard) - definitely contain metadata attributes already?  And in your request - do you ask for that scope information?

Comment: https://YOUR_TENANT.auth0.com/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&scope=openid profile&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&nonce=12345

Comment: pasting into answer

Answer (score 0):

Try starting up your application locally, then update the following URL with your own settings and paste it into a web browser:

```
https://YOUR_TENANT.auth0.com/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&scope=openid profile&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&nonce=12345
```

This should at least ensure you are making a request with right scopes etc. You should also ensure you have a User Profile with some "metadata" assigned if you are expecting to read that data post authentication of course ;)

Comment: Pasting the url asks me to login. Once I'm logged in, it redirects me to the callback.

Comment: I am not sure how it relates to the php sdk tho

Comment: My user's `user_metadata` is set to a very simple, and valid, json object string

Comment: Did you successfully login using the above?  Was the metadata available in either the id token or user profile?  if you have a profile with user_metadata: { foo = "bar" }  then put in an extra scope above with "scope=openid profile foo"   - what happens when you login?

Comment: You know, what it does is redirecting me to the callback, I don't see anything else happening. I am supposed to paste that url in the browser right?

Comment: If I click on the "Raw Json" tab of that user in my dashboard, I see a bunch of info related to this user, including the metadata. Of which, only a portion comes back to me when I call `->userinfo()` (I have updated the question to reflect this)